# How to get google calendar URL for specific logged in user

Tags: web-applications, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm developing web app and I want to show user (logged in my app with google account) a link, to open Google Calendar in new tab. I don't know how to manage it, when user has multiple Google Calendar sessions locally in their browser.

When I open Google Calendar for every session, URLs looks like this:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/2/r
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/3/r
```

The number after `/u/` depends on the order of logged user in browser session in Google Calendar. The problem is: I want to generate/retreive link to google calendar for a specific user which is logged in my web app. Where can I find it?

I've tried [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference) and searched for this problem here, but didn't find any information how to solve this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: just use https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r#g it should load up for their default calendar.

Comment: Related question on WebApps.SE: [Is it possible to bookmark a Google calendar or inbox for a specific account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86559/33787)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `authuser` parameter

`https://calendar.google.com/calendar?authuser=your@email.com`

In case there's no user found in your actives sessions, it will redirect to the default user.

Answer (score 1):

The Google calendar api gives you programmatic access to the data within google calendar for an authenticated user.  It has no access to the Google Calendar Web app

That being said if you use the following url it should open up to the users default calendar or whichever one their machine is currently signed in as.  Its basically the bookmark created when you book mark Google calendar in your browser.

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r#g
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But is there an option to open a non-default Google Calendar? Fe. User logged in in my app is logged in 3 accounts in Google Calendar, and link to account that is logged in my app is `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/2/r` which is not default calendar. Is there an option to do this?

Comment: not as far as i know  that link is going to default pop a user back to u/0 which is their own calendar.

Comment: Thank you! This was answer, that I was looking for ;)